# 401 unauthorized when trying to subscribe to a topic (FCM) from a cloud function in firebase

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-accounts

When i try to let a list of tokens subscribe to a topic of FCM from a firebase function after having initialized an app (using default service account), I get a 401 unauthorized.

I am using the Python firebase SDK

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
from firebase_admin import storage, db, auth, messaging, credentials


app = initialize_app()


@https_fn.on_call()
def subscribe_to_pool(req: https_fn.CallableRequest):
    return {
        "SUCCESS": messaging.subscribe_to_topic(
            req.data["tokens"], "pool"
        ).success_count
        == len(req.data["tokens"])
    }
```

Response

```
--- Logging error ---
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/sep/Desktop/sep/ypool/functions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 507, in make_topic_management_request
>      resp = self._client.body(
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    File "/home/sep/Desktop/sep/ypool/functions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 131, in body
>      resp = self.request(method, url, **kwargs)
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    File "/home/sep/Desktop/sep/ypool/functions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 119, in request
>      resp.raise_for_status()
>    File "/home/sep/Desktop/sep/ypool/functions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
>      raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
>  requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
```

The service account should have the permission scope Firebase Cloud Messaging Admin, so I don't see why this would not work. The service account being used is the default service account of firebase functions that I believe firebase directly creates when initiating the project <project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. I've given it every possible permission I can think of that it would need (including Firebase Admin)
[image: roles given to the service account]

When generating a cred JSON from the firebase console and creating a certificate when initializing the app, it does work, but that won't work in production since the JSON won't be accessible there, and the default service account should be enough.

Comment: Edit your post. Include details on the IAM roles that you granted to the function's attached service account. Make sure you know which service account is being used by your code.